# Calculate time complexity for the following snippet

Tags: time-complexity

Can someone please calculate the the no. of steps it will take to execute the above code?

And verify the solution, with some input values of n.

(found some relevant question, but not helping)

```
int count=0;
for(int i=1; i<=n ;i=i*2)
{
  for(int j=1; j<=i; j=j*2)
  {   
    count++;
  }
}
```

Comment: I calculated the steps  log n(log n  -1)/2, but not giving the correct result for values of n

Answer (score 0):

We can make a table:

```
i = 1: j = 1       --> 1 count
i = 2: j = 1,2     --> 2 counts
i = 4: j = 1,2,4   --> 3 counts
i = 8: j = 1,2,4,8 --> 4 counts
```

The pattern should be clear from here. We can reimagine the pattern such that i = 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., and instead of going from 1 to n, let's just say it goes from 1 to log n. This means that the total count should be the sum from i = 1 to log (base 2) n of i. The sum from i = 1 to x of i is simply x(x+1)/2, so if x = log_2(n), then this sum is simply (log_2(n) * log_2(n)+1)/2

**EDIT:** It seems like I made a mistake somewhere, and what I wrote is actually f(n/2) based on empirical tests. Thus, the correct answer is actually (log_2(2n) * log_2(2n)+1)/2. Nevertheless, this is the logic I would follow to solve a problem like this

**EDIT 2:** Caught my mistake. Instead of saying "let's just say it goes from 1 to log n", I should have said "let's just say it goes from 0 to log n" (i.e., I need to take the log of every number in the series)

Answer (score 0):

```
         inner-loop
i = 1 --> log(1)  = 0
i = 2 --> log(2)  = 1
i = 4 --> log(4)  = 2
i = 8 --> log(8)  = 3
i = 16 -> log(16) = 4
i = 32 -> log(32) = 5
i = 64 -> log(64) = 6
.
.
.
i = n -> log(n) = log(n)
```

That is the amount of work and it will stop after log(n) iterations as `i` hits `n`.

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 +...+ log(n) = [(1+log(n))*log(n)]/2 = O(log^2(n))
```

Comment: for i=1  inner loop is running once.

Comment: @Deven, this extra 1 operation doesn't change anything from the final complexity which is `O(log^2(n))`

Comment: for i=1  inner loop is running once.
so the sequence should be:

i=1  (2 raise power 0)  --->    1
i=2  (2 raise power 1)  --->    2
i=4  (2 raise power 2)  --->    3
i=8  (2 raise power 3)  --->    4
i=16  (2 raise power 4)  --->  5
.....
i= (2 raise power k-1)    ----> k

total iterations --->  1+2+3+.....k-1  = k(k+1) / 2

loop will end when 2 raise power k = n   i.e. k=log (n)   

so total iterations = log (n) (log (n)+1) / 2

                              ( log^2 (n) +log (n) ) / 2

Comment: yeah but i am trying to find the nearly exact one. But thanks , your solution gave me hint. (Not able to upvote!!)